# Why is this command for "Changing Where Screenshots Are Saved" failing?

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, screen-capture

Screenshots are being saved to the desktop but not in a specific folder. I want to remedy that so I found instructions to do so through Terminal. I am following the instructions but I am getting the message that it has NOT changed. Here is what has been entered...what do I have wrong?[image]

Comment: Your command should be `defaults write com.apple.screencapture location /Users/yourusername/Desktop/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have a space between `location` and `/Users/..`, there needs to be a space between *arguments*.

[image]

**Example:**

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture location /path/to/folder
```